# Suppress output from popen()

Tags: c, linux, ffmpeg, popen, suppress

Is there a way to suppress the output from `popen()` without losing the Wait().

**Test 1:**

```
FILE * stream = NULL;
char buffer [120];

stream = popen ("ffmpeg -y -i test.amr -ar 16000 test.wav -v quiet", "r");

while (fgets (buffer, sizeof(buffer), stream))
{
}

pclose (stream);
```

**Test 2:**

```
FILE * stream = NULL;
char buffer [120];

stream = popen ("ffmpeg -y -i test.amr -ar 16000 test.wav -v quiet &> /dev/null", "r");

while (fgets (buffer, sizeof(buffer), stream))
{
}

pclose (stream);
```

The problem with **Test 2** is that `pclose()` is not waiting for the pipe to finish processing.  I don't want to have a bunch of FFMPEG output every time I have to do a pipe.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the problem in the code. Could you post the actual output, describe the desired output, etc.? We programmers need input and output pipes too :)

Comment: Could `ffmpeg` be writing to `stderr` for some reason ? Could you try `ffmpeg ... 2> /dev/null` ?

Comment: @cnicutar Thanks `2>` solved the issue!

Comment: For future reference: `&>` redirects *both* standard-output *and* standard-error. To redirect only standard-output, use `>` or `1>`; to redirect only standard-error, use `2>`, as cnicutar suggested.

Comment: `&>` is nonstandard and should not be used. The standard way to redirect both is `>/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use `popen()` when you want to send data to, or read data from, the child process (and that is an exclusive-or; if you want to do both, you have to set up the connection yourself).

If you don't want to do that, don't use `popen()`.

As [jim mcnamara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348312/jim-mcnamara) accurately [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337597/suppress-output-from-popen/9337660#9337660), given that you redirect the output of the child to `/dev/null` after the pipe is created, the redirection closes the pipe input to your program, so `popen()` gets zero bytes to read, which counts as EOF.  And it returns - there is nothing more for it to read (if there might be more for it, it would not have received EOF).

In this context, use `system()`; it will wait for the child to finish - even when the output of the child is redirected to `/dev/null`.  In other contexts, it might be appropriate to use the lower-level `fork()` and `exec*()` routines instead.

Answer (score 1):

output to /dev/null means that popen (which is calling read() ) does not block on a closed file descriptor for stdout.    It returns right away.

You effectively closed stdout by redirecting it (dup() ), in reality it returns EOF